# Sometimes, not always, when loading an MSSQL table from Excel a new table suffixed with a $ is created by MSSQL. Why?

Tags: sql-server, excel, load

We are loading MSSQL tables via Microsoft Management Studio Import. Sometimes, not always, a new identical table is created in the load process with a $ at the end of the name. Why does this happen? Is this related to the IDs?

Comment: From https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5a5395d9-a075-46e7-ac0e-62c3bbd23fbb/datatable-names-with-symbols?forum=sqltools, "Excel object names that are appended with a dollar sign ($) represent worksheets (for example, Sheet1$), and that plain object names without the dollar sign represent Excel named ranges." Is it possible that this situation applies to you?

Comment: @DougDeden, I didn't know that. Smart. Don't be afraid to post it as possible answer

Answer (score 2):

From [this MSDN discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5a5395d9-a075-46e7-ac0e-62c3bbd23fbb/datatable-names-with-symbols?forum=sqltools):

> Excel object names that are appended with a dollar sign ($) represent worksheets (for example, Sheet1$), and that plain object names without the dollar sign represent Excel named ranges.

So the tables you are seeing with the dollar sign came from Excel worksheets.